# How can I draw a list with lines in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How would I paint a list of instructions that looks like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try [timelines](https://pub.dev/packages/timelines):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Timeline.tileBuilder(
    builder: TimelineTileBuilder.fromStyle(
      contentsAlign: ContentsAlign.alternating,
      contentsBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
        child: Text('Timeline Event $index'),
      ),
      itemCount: 10,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it´s really easy, flutter have a widget for it, it is called Stepper, this is the Stepper´s widget documentation link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html, research about this widget and you´ll make that design